# The method "enumerateChildNodesWithName" sometimes can't find the SpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making a side-scrolling video game with Sprite Kit of Objective-C.
When the character jumps from the bottom, I want it to slip through the bars. 
And When it jumps from above, I want it to get on the bars.

But, it does not work sometimes.

The method "enumerateChildNodesWithName" sometimes  can't find the SpriteNode.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    // LongBar
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:LONG_BAR usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
    {
        SKNode *gameCharacter = [ self childNodeWithName:GAME_CHARACTER];

        // The character is over the bar
        if(  node.position.y < gameCharacter.position.y )
        {
            node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = CONTACT_BAR;
            node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CONTACT_CHARACTER;
        }
        // The character is under the bar
        else
        {
            node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = 0;
            node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
        }
    }];

    // ShortBar
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:SHORT_BAR usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
    {
        // same as longbar
            :
            :
    }];
}
```

other info:
・There are two each of those long and short bar. 
　SpriteName is different.
・The short bar often does not work.
・The long/short bars are also created in the fixed cycle, 
　so same ones exists in the screen. 
・It worked well when it was modified to produce only long/short bars.

↓ 2014/07/17 add　↓

```
@property SKSpriteNode *longBar;
@property SKSpriteNode *shortBar;
    ：
    ：
#define LONG_BAR    @"long_bar"
#define SHORT_BAR   @"short_bar"
    :
    :
- (void) addShortBar
{
    size_t y;
    float x = 0.6f;

    y = ( arc4random() % ( (int)self.size.height / 2 ) )+ ( self.size.height / 3 );


    self.shortBar.name = SHORT_BAR;

    self.shortBar           = [ SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:BAR_SHORT];
    self.shortBar.size      = CGSizeMake(60 * x , 28 * x);

    self.shortBar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.shortBar.size];

    self.shortBar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, y);
    self.shortBar.physicsBody.affectedByGravity    = NO;
    self.shortBar.physicsBody.dynamic              = NO;
    self.shortBar.physicsBody.categoryBitMask      = CONTACT_BAR;
    self.shortBar.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask   = (CONTACT_CHARACTER | CONTACT_POINT);

    self.shortBar.physicsBody.restitution          = 0;

    [self.shortBar runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(BAR_IS_OUT, self.shortBar.position.y) duration:_timeBarPasses]];
    [self addChild:self.shortBar];

    [self addRareItem:y];       // method that add item

}
```

Comment: test if node has that name, and is added as child to "self" - also post how you create and add the sprite and what SHORT_BAR is

Comment: Thanks for comment. I added how to create and add shortBar.